# C: do-while free a linked list

Tags: c, loops, pointers, free

I have noticed that this works properly, but I wouldn't expect it to:

```
  do {
    free(params);
  } while ((params = params->next));
```

Normally I would use something like this, but doesn't look as elegant:

```
  do {
    params_t *next = params->next;
    free(params);
    params = next;
  } while (params);
```

(the code implies that `params` is allocated)

Or:

```
  while (params) {
    params_t *next = params->next;
    free(params);
    params = next;
  }
```

Probably unrelated, but I am using `-std=gnu11` with `clang`.

Is the first piece of code valid?

Comment: No. It's undefined behavior, and not guaranteed to work.

Comment: How are you obtaining the head of the list ?   The thing I learned when working with linked lists is that a list with N nodes has N-1 links.  Obvious when you know, mysterious, and often fatal when you don't.  Add a print statement into the body of all three loops, and physically count nodes and links.

Answer (score 3):

Your first version is not correct, it's undefined behavior to rely on the content of memory after calling `free()` on it. It might happen to work, but that's just undefined behavior happening to do something that seems well-defined. It really isn't.

You can of course just use the proper looping construct, and have a better life:

```
for (params_t *next; params != NULL; params = next)
{
  next = params->next;
  free(params);
}
```

This seems like a better match than the other alternatives, since you can use the various clauses of the `for` construct usefully. It's still a two-liner, but there's such a thing as too terse code too. :)

Comment: Using `for` is nice most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet

```
  do {
    free(params);
  } while ((params = params->next));
```

has undefined behaviour because there is an attempt to access an object that is not alive.

This code snippet

```
  do {
    params_t *next = params->next;
    free(params);
    params = next;
  } while (params);
```

is also wrong (provided that there is no check that params is equal to NULL before the loop) because in general `params` initially can be equal to NULL. The same problem exists for the first code snippet.

Only this code snippet

```
  while (params) {
    params_t *next = params->next;
    free(params);
    params = next;
  }
```

is valid.:)